# Problems with mountable engine's application controller

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan, rails-engines

I have a rails app called X and a rails mountable engine called Y.
App X has Devise and engine Y has CanCan which works with the hosts apps devise installation. In order to seperate the concerns of host app and mountable engine, the engine has a CanCan ability model as well as the host app.
My problem is the following, as per CanCan documentation you can change the default ability model like so https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Changing-Defaults.
My problem is that if I setup the of default ability class in the mountable engines application controller like so:

```
module Y
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
    def current_ability 
      @current_ability = Ability.new(current_user)
    end
  end
end
```

I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant Ability
```

(On a side note, when I edit the file and reload the page without restarting the server it works fine)

If however I put the same method into the host app's application controller:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def current_ability 
    @current_ability = Y::Ability.new(current_user)
  end
end
```

Everything works as expected (which also means that Devise and CanCan are setup correctly).

Anyone got any ideas of why this is happening? I might not understand mountable engines correctly however I always thought that they are isolated from the host app, thus when accessing a page defined by the mountable engine the host app's application controller shouldn't even be executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is most likely that your engines application controller is not loaded at all. Rails engines behave bad if you have same class name in the main app. [here is the issue if you want to look at.](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6413) I would recommend using the explicit declaration in your engine. Use Y::Ability instead of Ability.